# Merge on Nested Columns in Big query

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a table that has nested columns and we want to always retrieve the latest record for a given unique key. The table would be a 250-300 million row partitioned table. Is it a best practice to do a merge on this table which has 1 nested column with repeated values or keep inserting into the table and retrieve the most recent record for a given key?

Comment: AFAIK MERGE statement is for modifying a tables (UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE); nevertheless, could you please share more details about the purpose of retrieving the most recent record over MERGE usage? This context will be useful for possibly share best practices to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `MERGE` you will lose data - you won't be able to answer 'how did this record look 4 days ago?'. If you add new rows, you will be able to see the whole process of how the record changed through time.

With a `MERGE` querying for the latest record will be faster - but you need to decide if there's value on keeping historical data.